# Android bind with existing service across multiple apps

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have a Service implemented in a Module A. Now Apps B and C uses this library to bind with service using `bindService(service, connection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE)` but it always creates a new instance of Service. I'm using `Messenger` to return binder to the connection objects. If I use AIDL, how sharing the same service instance is achieved? I've read and tried almost all stackoverflow answers related to this question. But still I'm not able to achieve what I explained above.

Manifest of this Service is defined inside Module A with full process name for process attribute and exported,enabled are set to true.

```
 <service
        android:name="io.packagename.LocationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        android:process="io.packagename.locationService" />
```

LocationService-Class:

```
class LocationService extends Service {
        IncomingHandler handler = new IncomingHandler()
        Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler)

        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
           Log.d(TAG, "onBind")
           return messenger.binder
        }
      }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: please post your service class

Comment: @Lino It does not have much code but anyways added it. Thanks

Comment: thanks. How are you checking that more instances of the service have been created?

Comment: I used adb shell dumpsys activity services and also you can find your service instances in ADB device monitor

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html):

> As discussed in the Services document, you can create a service that
>   is both started and bound. That is, the service can be started by
>   calling startService(), which allows the service to run indefinitely,
>   and also allow a client to bind to the service by calling
>   bindService().

An example:

> For example, a music player might find it useful to allow its service
>   to run indefinitely and also provide binding. This way, an activity
>   can start the service to play some music and the music continues to
>   play even if the user leaves the application. Then, when the user
>   returns to the application, the activity can bind to the service to
>   regain control of playback.

I believe that applies to your case, so you can start the service and bind the clients to it as needed.

Comment: This is across activities. I asked about sharing it across apps.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have enough reputation to reply above comment.)

> This is across activities. I asked about sharing it across apps

Yes this applies to cross applications. I'm using this approach for 3 separated apks with different package names.